# Not able to write Prototype function as Function Declarations in javascript. Why?

Tags: javascript

Why can not we write prototype function like function declaration:

only it is allowed in function expression:

```js
       function SinglyLinkedList() {
         this.head = null;
         this.tail = null;
       }
  
        SinglyLinkedList.prototype.add = function(data){
         console.log(data);
        } // working as expected

        function SinglyLinkedList.prototype.add(data){
         console.log(data);
        }
        // showing error.
```

Comment: What's allowed in function expressions, could you show an example.?

Comment: updated the code

Comment: `SinglyLinkedList.prototype.add =` this is not creating a function,  this is -> `function(data){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's just not how the syntax is designed. Maybe it *could* have been designed that way, but it wasn't. The *name* (more precisely, *binding identifier*) in a [function declaration](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-FunctionDeclaration) must match the definition of an [*Identifier*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-Identifier), which means it cannot be a property path like `SinglyLinkedList.prototype.add`.

Note that if you're looking for something shorter, you could use `Object.assign` (new, but polyfillable) and an object initializer using method syntax (new as of ES2015):

```
Object.assign(SinglyLinkedList.prototype, {
    add(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    remove(/*...*/) {
        // ...
    }
    // etc.
});
```

Or for pre-ES2015 environments (with a polyfill for `Object.assign`), property syntax rather than method syntax:

```
Object.assign(SinglyLinkedList.prototype, {
    add: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    remove: function(/*...*/) {
        // ...
    }
    // etc.
});
```

And of course, ES2015+ has `class` which is also more concise than the old way.

Answer (score 2):

After the `function` keyword, you're allowed to write a function name. The function name must conform to valid naming conventions. `.` is invalid in a function name, making the syntax invalid.

The `function` keyword was simply not designed to create a function on a nested object. Its only job is to create a function, it's not concerned with where you put it afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

The second method is not syntactically valid in JS

One possible way to assign a named function to a prototype:

```
function add(data) {
    ...
}

SinglyLinkedList.prototype.add = add;
```